# Solve for y: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = A\sin(y)+B\cos(y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, nonlinear-analysis

**Current Progress**
I am currently unable to proceed further, any help is welcomed. Looks forward to seeing different approaches to this differential equation.

$
{y}'' = A\sin(y) + B\cos(y)
\\g(y)=A\sin{(y)}+B\cos{(y)}
\\ {y}'' {y}'dx=g(y) {y}'dx
\\ {y}'d{y}'=g(y)dy
\\\frac{1}{2} {y}'^2=\int g(y)dy
\\ {y}' = \pm \sqrt {2\int g(y)dy}
\\ dx = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\int g(y)dy}} dy
\\x=\pm\int\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\int g(y)dy}}dy
\\x=\pm\int\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\int {(A\sin{(y)}+B\cos{(y)})}dy}} dy
\\x=\pm\int\frac{1}{\sqrt {2B\sin{(y)}-2A\cos{(y)}+C}} dy
$

Comment: Is there something that makes you think that this highly nonlinear ODE has a closed form solution?

Comment: Converting $(A,B)$ to polar coordinates so that $A = R\cos \theta$ and $B = R\sin\theta$ gives that $A\sin y + B\cos y = R \sin(y+\theta)$, which makes this slightly simpler.

Comment: Looks like this can be expressed in terms of the Jacobi amplitude function.

Comment: It is equivalent to $y''=a\sin(y+b)$ and $y'' y'=a\sin(y+b)y'$ and $\frac 12y'^2=c-a\cos(y+b)$ which is separable, resulting in a Jacoby-amplitude function.